# Edit Customize Change Justification rules to solve losse lines in tight columns or spaces

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, typography, columns

I'm working on a table and have a column (column 3) which is about 5 cm wide (specifically set) where I'd like text to be justified. However, due to the tight column, the paragraph style (in combo with microtype package) creates text which is spaced or 'stretched' too much for my linkings. I'd like to edit the rules which are used for justification to: allow for justification when words more or less end near the column border, but disable the justification (or the wordspacing) if the words do NOT come close to the border, because this stretches the text unnaturally (!!!especially because some are separate sentences (or New lines) starting/ending with a `\linebreak`.

In the provided example, especially the text in column 3, last three rows, the spacing is not 'nice'.

I've tried `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}` , but doesnt give me the result I want. Maybe I'm too picky but I want some justification, not full justification.

Should I start the new lines within the table with something else than `\linebreak` ?
Can I edit the rules for justification by setting max wordspacing or ..? 
Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,openright,11pt,reqno]{report}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{footmisc}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{tabular}[c]{|>{\centering}p{0.5cm}|p{2.7cm}|p{5.3cm}|p{4.5cm}|} 
\hline
\textbf{No.} & \textbf{Col2}    
                        & \textbf{Column3}
                                            & \textbf{Goal of the }\\  
\hline \hline   
\textbf{1}  & TL-TL and \linebreak PAL-PAL      
                        & TL: max climb thrust to low idle \linebreak PAL: -2 degrees to +3 degrees 
                                            & text \\ \hline
\textbf{2}  & PAL-PAL   & from 0 degrees to (+4 until +15) degrees  
                                            & text\\ \hline
\textbf{3}  & PAL-PAL   & from 0 degrees to (-4 until -15) degrees  
                                            & text\\ \hline
\textbf{4}  & TL-SL\footnotemark[4]-TL-SL \linebreak (PAL)      
                        & TL: from 0.01 to 0.242\footnotemark[6] \linebreak SL: from 200 to 280 knots \linebreak SL: from 0.5 to 0.75 Mach \linebreak (PAL): from -2 degrees to +3 degrees     
                                            & text\\ \hline
\textbf{5}  & TL-SL-TL-SL \linebreak (VSL)      
                        & TL: from 0.01 to 0.242\footref{fn:6} \linebreak SL: from 200 to 280 knots \linebreak (VSL): from -300 feet per minute to +300 feet per minute         
                                            & text\\ \hline
\textbf{6}  & TL-PAL-TL-PAL \linebreak (SL)     
                        & TL: from 0.01 to 0.242\footref[6] \linebreak PAL: from -2 degrees to +3 degrees \linebreak (SL): from 200 to 280 kt       
                                            & text\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption[short ]{long . \label{tab:test:testvars}}
\bigskip
\end{table}
\footnotetext[4]{\textbf{Note:} SL (Speed Law)in knots.\label{fn:4}}
\footnotetext[5]{\textbf{Note:} SL (Speed Law) in Mach number.\label{fn:5}}
\footnotetext[6]{\textbf{Note:} TL (Thrust Laws) are expressed in thrust coefficient.\label{fn:6}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: try `>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}` with capital R from the `ragged2e` package which provides less ragged setting than the usual latex one

Comment: Thanks alot @DavidCarlisle, that did smooth out some texts. I'm using that now. But it did not fully answer the question if there are customizing options as to, lets say, tweak manually..?